# How can I provide a default configuration file with puppet but allow the server administrator to update it

Tags: linux, puppet, ubuntu-12.04

I'd like to provide a "default-example" configuration file to node servers using puppet (my.cnf for example) but I want to allow the server administrator to update it as much as he wants. (Basically, I provide "base" vm to IT researchers and they adapt it by themselves)

I' tried with the function "file" with puppet but it noticed when I try to change it...

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the *replace* parameter for [file](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file).

```
file { '/path/to/file':
  ensure  => present,
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/module_name/file',
  replace => false,
}
```

If this is a production environment I would recommend encouraging/requiring the admins to make configuration changes via puppet. If this is not a production environment you could use puppet to do the configuration (like with '[puppet apply](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/man/apply.html)') and not continue to run puppet agent after that.

Comment: Ho... didn't see that option ! works fine ! thank you

Answer (score 2):

Anton's answer is probably best however this method might be useful as well.

Mysql supports conf directories. I usually have a single line in my.cnf, !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/ and then load additional configs to fill in functionality. Mysql will use the last instance of a config variable based on parse order. If you put your defaults in /etc/mysql/conf.d/00_somefile.cnf any additional files should override it. You might create a /etc/mysql/conf.d/local_changes.cnf so it's clear where to put it.

```
class mysql::config {

  file { 'my.cnf':
    ensure  => present,
    path    => '/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    source  => 'puppet:///modules/mysql/my.cnf',
  }

  file { '/etc/mysql/conf.d':
    ensure  => directory,
  }

  file { 'general_mysql.cnf':
    ensure  => present,
    path    => '/etc/mysql/conf.d/00_general_mysql.cnf',
    content => template('mysql/general_mysql.cnf.erb'),
  }
```

With the above you can continue to publish changes via your Puppet controlled config file and the researchers can override as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I don't know how MySQL would react if we set the engine to innodb via puppet and then the admin wants to configure another engine using a conf file in the /etc/mysql/conf.d

Comment: Both engines would likely be enabled which might be suboptimal though you could try skip-innodb in a later config and see if it would cancel it out. I tend to use this technique of dev machines where the vhosts may change frequently, but I still want to set reasonable defaults for modules that can be overridden per vhost.